# No effect of “size” in ‘query’ while reindexing in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have been using logstash to migrate a index to another. I have recently tried to reindex certain amount of data from large dataset in local environment. So I tried using following configuration for migration:

```
input{
  elasticsearch{
    hosts=>"localhost:9200"
    index=>"old_indexindex"
    query=>'{"query":{"match_all":{}},"size":10 }'
  }
}filter{
  mutate{
    remove_field=>[
      "@version",
      "@timestamp"
    ]
  }
}output{
  elasticsearch{
    hosts=>"localhost:9200"
    index=>"new_index"
    document_type=>"contact"
    manage_template=>false
    document_id=>"%{contactId}"
  }
}
```

But this reindexes all the documents in **old_index** to **new_index**, where as , I was expecting just **10** documents to be reindexed in new_index. 
Am I missing some concept using logstash with elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `elasticsearch` input doesn't make a conventional search, but does a [scan/scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html) search type instead. This means that all data will be retrieved from the index and the role of the `size` parameter just serves to define **how much data** will be fetched during each scroll, not how much data will be fetched altogether.

Also, note that the `size` parameter in the query itself has no effect. You need to use the [`size` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-inputs-elasticsearch-size) of the `elasticsearch` input and not specify it in the query.

```
input{
  elasticsearch{
    hosts=> "localhost:9200"
    index=> "old_index"
    query=> '*'
    size => 10                 <--- size goes here
  }
}
```

That being said, if you're running ES 2.3 or later, there's a way to achieve what you desire using the [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html), like this:

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "size": 10,
  "source": {
    "index": "old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index"
  }
}
```

Comment: This was helpful. I was just trying get tue query working as for elasticsearch query alike.